# Method <...> is missing in <...> or has incorrect signature

Tags: java, android

I keep getting `Method 'onClickGreeting' is missing in 'Home' or has incorrect signature` warning in XML file and the app crashes when clicking on the button.

I tried doing Clean Project but nothing changed.

The method was created first manually, then I tried Android studio's fix:
[image: Android studio's fix]

This created an identical signature to the one I already wrote.

**Home.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.apptest.databinding.HomeBinding;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    private HomeBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = HomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        binding.btnShowRandomPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(Home.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

    public void onClickGreeting(View view) {
        Context context = getContext();
        CharSequence text = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.greeting), binding.userName.getText());
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

**home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_generate_greeting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:onClick="onClickGreeting"
        android:text="@string/button_show_greeting"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

..........................................................................

Comment: onClick method in xml (as you have used) only works for activity and not for fragments.
Here as per your code android will look for  "onClickGreeting" method in Home activity and will not look in fragment.

Comment: @DB377 OP is using binding ... so it should work

Comment: you may always use `binding.(btn_generate_greeting).setOnClickListener(this::onClickGreeting)` where `(btn_generate_greeting)` is translation id to variable in databinding (prolly camel case without underscores)... also it may be some kinfd of typo as you are using  `binding.btnShowRandomPhoto` but there is no such button in your layout

Comment: @DB377 thanks! Since the XML is linked to a fragment shouldn't Android Studio show a different warning or suggest a different fix?

Comment: @Selvin sorry, `btnShowRandomPhoto` is another button I have in Home fragment but I didn't include it in the sample code... Given yours and @DB377 's comment I ended up using `binding.btnGenerateGreeting.setOnClickListener` and now it works